# TypeError during Jest's spyOn: Cannot set property getRequest of #<Object> which has only a getter

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, spy, spyon

I'm writing a React application with TypeScript. I do my unit tests using Jest.

I have a function that makes an API call:

```
import { ROUTE_INT_QUESTIONS } from "../../../config/constants/routes";
import { intQuestionSchema } from "../../../config/schemas/intQuestions";
import { getRequest } from "../../utils/serverRequests";

const intQuestionListSchema = [intQuestionSchema];

export const getIntQuestionList = () => getRequest(ROUTE_INT_QUESTIONS, intQuestionListSchema);
```

The `getRequest` function looks like this:

```
import { Schema } from "normalizr";
import { camelizeAndNormalize } from "../../core";

export const getRequest = (fullUrlRoute: string, schema: Schema) =>
  fetch(fullUrlRoute).then(response =>
    response.json().then(json => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        return Promise.reject(json);
      }
      return Promise.resolve(camelizeAndNormalize(json, schema));
    })
  );
```

I wanted to try the API function using Jest like this:

```
import fetch from "jest-fetch-mock";
import { ROUTE_INT_QUESTIONS } from "../../../config/constants/routes";
import {
  normalizedIntQuestionListResponse as expected,
  rawIntQuestionListResponse as response
} from "../../../config/fixtures";
import { intQuestionSchema } from "../../../config/schemas/intQuestions";
import * as serverRequests from "./../../utils/serverRequests";
import { getIntQuestionList } from "./intQuestions";

const intQuestionListSchema = [intQuestionSchema];

describe("getIntQuestionList", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    fetch.resetMocks();
  });

  it("should get the int question list", () => {
    const getRequestMock = jest.spyOn(serverRequests, "getRequest");
    fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify(response));

    expect.assertions(2);
    return getIntQuestionList().then(res => {
      expect(res).toEqual(expected);
      expect(getRequestMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ROUTE_INT_QUESTIONS, intQuestionListSchema);
    });
  });
});
```

The problem is that the line with `spyOn` throws the following error:

```
  ● getRestaurantList › should get the restaurant list

    TypeError: Cannot set property getRequest of #<Object> which has only a getter

      17 |
      18 |   it("should get the restaurant list", () => {
    > 19 |     const getRequestMock = jest.spyOn(serverRequests, "getRequest");
         |                                 ^
      20 |     fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify(response));
      21 |
      22 |     expect.assertions(2);

      at ModuleMockerClass.spyOn (node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:706:26)
      at Object.spyOn (src/services/api/IntQuestions/intQuestions.test.ts:19:33)
```

I googled this and only found posts about hot reloading. So what could cause this during Jest test? How can I get this test to pass?

Comment: You need to use `jest.mock()` on es6 module objects which do not have setters

Comment: @Volodymyr Could you explain how you would do that? I don't really understand. I've never encountered the topic of getters and setters. Also this test passes for me on React Native. Only on regular React it fails.

Comment: Weird.  The error is happening on [this line](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/5b7c75d4c36f60578ef29175cac09901eefb613d/packages/jest-mock/src/index.js#L801) where jest tries to replace the property `getRequest` on the `serverRequests` module object.  I can't recreate the issue.  Is the `serverRequests` module being modified somewhere else (globally mocked maybe)?  For some reason `getRequest` is ending up as a getter property on the imported module object which keeps it from being replaced by the spy.

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors In `serverRequests/` there is an `index.ts` that imports all the requests and exports them again, so that I can do `import { getRequest } from "../../utils/serverRequests";`. Could that be the reason?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

This one was interesting.

### Issue

`Babel` generates properties with only `get` defined for re-exported functions.

`utils/serverRequests/index.ts` re-exports functions from other modules so an error is thrown when `jest.spyOn` is used to spy on the re-exported functions.

---

### Details

Given this code re-exporting everything from `lib`:

```js
export * from './lib';
```

...`Babel` produces this:

```js
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

var _lib = require('./lib');

Object.keys(_lib).forEach(function (key) {
  if (key === "default" || key === "__esModule") return;
  Object.defineProperty(exports, key, {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function get() {
      return _lib[key];
    }
  });
});
```

Note that the properties are all defined with only `get`.

Trying to use `jest.spyOn` on any of those properties will generate the error you are seeing because `jest.spyOn` tries to replace the property with a spy wrapping the original function but can't if the property is defined with only `get`.

---

### Solution

Instead of importing `../../utils/serverRequests` (which re-exports `getRequest`) into the test, import the module where `getRequest` is defined and use that module to create the spy.

### Alternate Solution

Mock the entire `utils/serverRequests` module as suggested by @Volodymyr and @TheF

Comment: Interestingly, `tsc` and `ts-jest` generate normal properties for re-exported functions which is why I had a hard time recreating the issue initially.

Answer (score 31):

Tested with `ts-jest` as compiler, it will work if you mock the module in this way:

```
import * as serverRequests from "./../../utils/serverRequests";

jest.mock('./../../utils/serverRequests', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  ...jest.requireActual('./../../utils/serverRequests')
}));

const getRequestMock = jest.spyOn(serverRequests, "getRequest");
```

[Jest official doc for `__esModule`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options)

Comment: This is a good answer too. I tried this because I had to spyOn an Azure module of which I could not import the submodule directly, neither mock manually the entire object, as stated by @brian-adams. This code will mock automatically the imported library.

Comment: +1 This _might_ be the best answer, because of **..jest.requireActual('./../../utils/serverRequests')**.

Answer (score 29):

As suggested in the comments, jest requires a setter on the tested object which es6 module objects don't have. `jest.mock()` allows you solving this by mocking your required module after the import.

Try mocking the exports from your serverRequests file

```
import * as serverRequests from './../../utils/serverRequests';
jest.mock('./../../utils/serverRequests', () => ({
    getRequest: jest.fn()
}));

// ...
// ...

it("should get the int question list", () => {
    const getRequestMock = jest.spyOn(serverRequests, "getRequest")
    fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify(response));

    expect.assertions(2);
    return getIntQuestionList().then(res => {
        expect(res).toEqual(expected);
          expect(getRequestMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ROUTE_INT_QUESTIONS, intQuestionListSchema);
    });
});
```

Here are some useful links: 
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions

Comment: the links you shared helped me find the missing pieces to es6 class mocks!

Comment: Good answer thanks, it's something I always have to get back on.  
A couple of additional points. 
1) I don't think you need to spyOn the `getRequest` method here since you mocked it as a jest function. You could just `import { getRequest } from '....` and pass that to the expectation.  
2) If you want to keep the original implementation of the getRequest method you can do 
`getRequest: jest.fn(jest.requireActual(...path).getRequest'`

Answer (score 11):

Recently we hit something like this in library we were using. Babel was only providing getters for all the members that were exported from the library, so we did this at the top of the test:

```
jest.mock('some-library', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('some-library')
}));
```

This fixed the issue, as it created a new, plain-old JS object with a member for every property in the library.

Comment: Unless you're mocking any implementations at the same time, the above can be done more simply as `import * as myModuleRaw from 'myModule'; const myModule = { ...myModuleRaw};`. If you're going to use `jest.spyOn()` for any of the methods, you'll need the module as an object anyway.

Answer (score 6):

If you wish to leave your import unmodified, you can fix the issue this way:

```
import * as lib from './lib'

jest.mock('./lib/subModule')

it('can be mocked', () => {
  jest.spyOn(lib, 'subModuleFunction')
})
```

You'll need to add more `jest.mock` lines for any additional re-exported functions you wish to spy on.

Comment: I have to say that extra line of jest.mock easily saves many lives. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else having this issue you can set babel to use "loose" transformations which solved the problem for me. Just set it in your .babelrc file as so

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "loose": true
    }]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrades on Jest Unit-Tests fail, when crossing:

```
export * from './serverRequests';
```

Reference the files directly to avoid "...has only a getter" issues!