# How to mock vuex functions with no direct access?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuex, vue-test-utils

So I have run into quite a test problem.

To Summarize:
A while back I created a private npm Module, that manages and create a vuex store and injects it as a module into the main vuex store.

Now I want to mock a specific function of that vuex module in my test but that doesn't work.

I tried this:

```
store.getters.getSomething = jest.fn(() => "stuff);
```

But that results in this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property getSomething of #<Object> which has only a getter
```

Now did a little digging, and I here you can see where this getter comes from:

First there is a simple vuex module definition:

```
//vuexModule  this is not accessible outside of the npm module
getters:{ 
      getSomething: (state)=>{ return "stuff"}
}
export { getters }
```

Now this is imported into this class:

```
//storeProvider  //this is exposed by the npm package
import vuexModule from "./vuexModule";

export default class StoreProvider {
  constructor(vuexStore, vuexModuleName = "someStore") {
    this.vuexStore = vuexStore;
    this.vuexStore.registerModule(vuexModuleName, VuexConfigStore);
}
```

So this class will generate a vuex module using the previously defined module.

Now the whole thing is added to the main vuex store in the actual application.
Note: this code is now the actual application and not in the npm package.

```
import StoreProvider from "someNpmModule"; 
import mainStore from "vuexPlugin"; 

const storeProvider = new StoreProvider(store);

//later in main: 
new Vue({ mainStore })
```

**So the question is: How can I mock getSomething?**
I know the code is quite abstracted, but I can't show all the code, and its probably too much for stackoverflow.

The main point is, that I can just import the getter and mock it like this:

```
import {getSomething} from "..."; 
getSomething = jest.fn(() => "stuff);
//Or this: 
store.getters.getSomething = jest.fn(() => "stuff);
```

I found this stackoverflow question: [TypeError during Jest's spyOn: Cannot set property getRequest of #<Object> which has only a getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53162001/typeerror-during-jests-spyon-cannot-set-property-getrequest-of-object-which)

But as the npm package is rather big I can't just mock the whole package for the unit tests, as it provides some necessary pre-conditions. I tried genMockFromModule(), but I still need to target this specific function.
And as mentioned I can't simply import the function.

Any ideas?

Comment: Using encapsulation to make testing difficult later is a footgun. Expose API that is needed for testing purposes. If it deserves to be a separate module, it likely should be mocked entirely or not mocked at all. Why do you insist on using a real one? This efficiently makes your tests integration tests.

Comment: I haven planned for mocking. Thought I could simply mock a vuex getter out of the box. Encapsuling a vuex store does make sense to me, and generating/adding it with registerModule too. Out of the the perspective of the npm package it doesn't make sense to expose the API of the vuex store, when its never used directly. Atleast that was the case till now with tests.